# Please merge the old "weddings" tag into the new "marriage" tag as the latter is more inclusive

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

We just got a question involving [marriage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage) but not weddings though I noticed we already have a [weddings](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weddings) tag.

Yes marriage and weddings are different things but "marriage" encompasses weddings and with such a small number of such questions it's currently beneficial to just use the one tag with the wider meaning.

We can always split them in the future if we find we have dozens of questions of each type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done, thank you for your work on tags for this site.

Comment: No worries mate (-;

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight change, changing the main tag to a plural [marriages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriages).

Comment: Yeah "marriage" is a funny word in that it can be an abstract noun or a concrete noun so works both as uncountable and countable. So whichever way doesn't make much difference.

Comment: While grammatically correct, I think "marriage", the uncountable abstract noun would have been better.